# Nested form in Play! Scala 2.2

Tags: scala, nested-forms, playframework-2.2

I have read several times the documentation but I still have problems with my nested form in Play! Scala 2.2 (detailed further).

Here is my form :

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/test2">
    first name : <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
    info 0 : <input type="text" name="label[0]"> <br>
    info 1 : <input type="text" name="label[1]"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="test nested form" />
</form>
```

And the case classes corresponding :

```
case class Contact(firstname: String,
               informations: Seq[ContactInformation])

case class ContactInformation(label: String)


 val contactForm: Form[Contact] = Form(
    mapping(
      "firstname" -> nonEmptyText,
      "informations" -> seq(
        mapping(
          "label" -> nonEmptyText
        )(ContactInformation.apply)(ContactInformation.unapply)
      )
    )(Contact.apply)(Contact.unapply)
  )

  def saveContact = Action { implicit request =>
    contactForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => Ok("error"),
      contact => {
        println(contact)
        Ok("Done")
      }
    )
  }
```

I don't get any errors, but the contact that I get from the form (printed with `println(contact)`) has an empty informations field, i.e. it looks like this : `Contact(h,List())`

The error comes probably from the `html` part since I have followed to the letter the documentation from this page : [play! scala forms documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaForms)
but I can’t figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field names of the `input`s should use the full path in the `Form`. `label` appears within the `informations` `Mapping`, and `informations` is the sequence, not the `label`, so you should use `informations[0].label` instead of `label[0]`.

Your view should look like this:

```
first name : <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br>
info 0 : <input type="text" name="informations[0].label"> <br>
info 1 : <input type="text" name="informations[1].label"> <br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it still doesn't work (same result), there is probably an other error in my code.