# Mapping OneToMany in Scala Play framework not inserting data to the second table

Tags: scala, playframework, one-to-many, psql, sorm

Question is - how should I take data from this kind of inputs and pass it properly to DB (by SORM framework)?

I try to pass data to two tables in my DB, the result of my work is that while the values are properly inserted to the first table (Author), second one (Book) remains untouched.
Probably my problem is that I am not propely naming nested, repeated inputs on my page, but i cant find proper way to do this (I'm fairly new to Scala, so I probably lack of experience on this).

```
Ok(Json.toJson(author))
```

in addData in Application.scala shows me

```
{"name":"what","books":[]}
```

so I think, that the problem is in binding data from request.

I tried to follow examples here: [How to model an entity with many children in Sorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863337/how-to-model-an-entity-with-many-children-in-sorm) and here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaForms, by operating on the template "play-scala" from Play framework, so i've got code like this:

Models are:

```
case class Author(name: String, books: Seq[Book]) {
}
object Author {
implicit val authorFormat = Json.format[Author]
}

case class Book(title: String ) {
}
object Book {
implicit val bookFormat = Json.format[Book]
}

case class AuthorBook(name: Author, title: Book) {
}
```

The scala.index.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        On the left Author, on the right Book
        <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <ul id="authors"></ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul id="books"></ul>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <form action="@routes.Application.addData()" method ="post">
        <tr>
            <td>Author: <input name="author" type="text">
        </td>       
            <td>Books: <input name="books.title[0]" type="text"><br><input name="books.title[1]" type="text">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 
                <button>Submit</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

And Application.scala

```
class Application extends Controller {
def index = Action {
Ok(views.html.index("E-Library"))
}

  val authorForm: Form[Author] = Form {
    mapping(
      "author" -> text,
      "books" -> seq(
          mapping(
          "title" -> text)(Book.apply)(Book.unapply)
      )
   )(Author.apply)(Author.unapply)
   }

  def error = Action {
    Ok("error")
  }

  def addData = Action { implicit request =>
      authorForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => {
      BadRequest("Bad request!")
    },
    authorF => {
      val author = DB.save(authorF)
      Ok(Json.toJson(author))
      //Redirect(routes.Application.index())
    }
  )
  }

  def getAuthor = Action {
    val dataAuthor = DB.query[Author].fetch
    Ok(Json.toJson(dataAuthor))
  }

  def getBook = Action {
    val dataBook = DB.query[Book].fetch
    Ok(Json.toJson(dataBook))
 }

  def getData = Action {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
As mentioned here: [Nested form in Play! Scala 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507983/nested-form-in-play-scala-2-2)

I needed to rename input names in my form from
    `book.title[0]`
to
    `book[0].title`.